# Is There A Downside To Calling Models From Helpers In CakePHP?

Tags: model-view-controller, caching, cakephp, helper, controllers

A bit of context: I need to cache the homepage of my CakePHP site - apart from one small part, which displays events local to the user based on their IP address.

You can obviously use the <cake:nocache> tag to dictate a part of the page that shouldn't be cached; but you can't surround a controller-set variable with these tags to make it dynamic.  Once a page is cached, that's it for the controller action, as far as I know.

What you *can* usefully surround with the nocache tags are elements and helpers.  As such, I've created an element inside these tags, which calls a helper function to access the model and get the appropriate data.  To get at the model from the helper I'm using:

```
$this->Modelname =& ClassRegistry::init("Modelname");
```

This seems to me, however, to be a kind of iffy way of doing things, both in terms of CakePHP and general MVC principles.  So my question is, is this an appropriate way of getting what I want to do done, or should it ring warning bells?  Is there a much better way of achieving my objectives that I'm just missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than breaking all the carefully-laid principles of MVC?

In addition to putting this item into an element, why not fetch it with a trivial bit of ajax?

1. Put the call in its own controller action, such that the destination URL -> /controller/action (quite convenient!)
2. Pass the IP back to that action for use in the find call
3. Set the ajax update callback to target within the element with the results of the call accordingly

No need to muck around calling Models directly from Views, and no need to bog things down with requestAction. :)

HTH

Comment: Sounds good.  Would you think that an ajax fetch would be inherently better than using requestAction?  It's easy for me to see that I have various options that are better than my original hasty plan, harder to tell why one is much better than the other...

Comment: In probably 90% of all situations where a view-stage object needs independent data, yeah, ajax > requestAction. MVC is like paddling a canoe full of goodies down a river. requestAction -> you turn around and paddle Cake back up the river. Ajax -> you call your pal on your cell phone to float the data down on an inner tube. (In a cooler. ;) ) It might be a little soggy, but it beats paddling back up the river. Ergo -> PHP's requestAction() has to move backwards through to get from where $this is a la View; ajax triggering your controller action = teleport to the beginning, with a fresh $this.

Comment: Thanks, your canoe analogies have convinced me, I'll give it a whirl ;)

Comment: I don't get the arguments for this here - with AJAX you have the overhead of an extra HTTP request and the extra complication of javascript to deal with. The difference in performance between something that happens on the server (requestAction) and over the network (AJAX) will be orders of scale, not to mention any work the browser has to do in reflowing content (think how this may work on mobile devices for instance). Granted there may be some lazy-loading situations where this could be a useful technique.

Comment: >_> How exactly is jQuery .post is "too complex," in contrast to managing requestAction in a layout? Cake is notoriously slow and bloated, thanks to a magically adhesive $this. Handling highly dynamic site-wide data proc with synchronous server calls stopped being cool in 2001. I have difficulty imagining how anybody manages a coherent app without judicious use of this particular technique, given that its mature implementation -> breaking out into abstraction / extension in components / AppController, etc. (without dropping browsers completely -> getting righteous with some Flex, anyway.)

Comment: Hi @satyr, I wasn't saying "too complex", just more complex than needed for this problem IMHO. `requestAction` isn't anything as weighty as a synchronous server call, it's more like a method call, all handled within the same PHP request. Have a look at Mark Story's requestAction benchmarks here, the difference between getting data directly from a model and using requestAction comes in at about 1%: http://cakedc.com/mark_story/2009/02/27/benchmarking-requestaction

Comment: @Contrebis - I've seen it, and Mark Story also suggests swapping out MooTools for pagination effects with requestAction, which I'm not a fan of. But in reference to **the OP's question context about acting on data unique to every visitor and every visit while exempting it from caching** -> ajax > requestAction. -- Also, fwiw I deeply doubt Mark Story has difficultly avoiding "wrong" requestAction calls, or needs advice from me on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a Helper, try to put your code in an element and use requestAction inside of the element.

see this link

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/gwoo/2007/04/12/creating-reusable-elements-with-requestaction

This would be a much better approach than trying to use a model in your helper.

Comment: Aha!  This seems a lot better than doing contortions to give access to the model inside of a Helper.  A further question though: the Cookbook section on requestAction says "if used without caching requestAction can lead to poor performance... requestAction is best used in conjunction with (cached) elements".  Obviously I feel a bit nervous reading this when I'm using requestAction explicitly on an element I *don't* want to be cached!  Would you say this is the right track to be on anyway?  Thank you!

Comment: there's been quite a bit of discussion on this in the past, outcome seemed to be that the overhead was generally acceptable for using requestAction. I'd personally want to check script memory usage if this is likely to be a constraint on your server. By the way, if you are worried about dependencies between helpers and models don't look at the code for FormHelper, you may have nightmares.